# Mixed Mode RVM giving error when used in init script

Tags: rvm, ubuntu-10.04, passenger

I've installed RVM in Mixed Mode and have Phusion Passenger running in stand alone mode.

I've found this init script to start my Phusion Passenger standalone server on startup: http://memcloud.com/note/show/167

Modifying only the prescribed values, it was giving me the following error, but would still run

```
-su: /home/myuser/.rvm/bin/rvm: No such file or directory
```

I ran `which rvm` in `myuser` and found out that RVM is in `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`. So I updated the `RVM` variable to reflect that, and changed `RVM="$USER_HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm"` to `RVM="/usr/local/rvm/bin/rv"`. Now it's giving me the following message, but it still runs.

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
```

Not really sure if it's a problem if the system is running, but I'd just like to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this script is wrong, you should use something more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO 
# Provides:          my-app passenger in standalone 
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5 
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6 
# Short-Description: Start/stop my-app web site 
### END INIT INFO 

# BEGIN MINIMAL CHANGES
USER=www-data
USER_HOME=/var/www
APP_PATH=/var/www/my-app/current
GEM_SET=ruby-1.8.7-p330@my-app
ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
PORT=3000
ENVIRONMENT=production
# END MINIMAL CHANGES

RVM="/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm"
PASSENGER="$USER_HOME/.rvm/gems/$GEM_SET/bin/passenger"
PASSENGER="cd $APP_PATH; $RVM $GEM_SET do $PASSENGER"

CMD_START="$PASSENGER start -a $ADDRESS -p $PORT -e $ENVIRONMENT -d"
CMD_STOP="$PASSENGER stop -p $PORT"

. /lib/lsb/init-functions
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting myapp passenger" 
    echo $CMD_START
    su - $USER -c "$CMD_START"
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping myapp passenger" 
    echo $CMD_STOP
    su - $USER -c "$CMD_STOP"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

you could also replace `GEM_SET=.` to make rvm use ruby stored in `.rvmrc` but this requires that `$USER` trusted that `.rvmrc` ... which could be also done in this script with:

```
su - $USER -c "rvm rvmrc trust $APP_PATH"
```

called as first line in `start)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what it gave me when I tried executing the script: `-su: /home/myapp/.rvm/bin/rvm: No such file or directory`